# Unable to map inside an async function

Tags: node.js, arrays, reactjs, api, async-await

In the below code, I am fetching data from an external api. After parsing the data as json, I wanted to map through it and get a modified version.

For some reason, the console.log(jsonData) inside the map function is not getting executed. Please check the code below for clarity

```
const getRandomOutfit = async (req, res) => {
  const { gender, countryCode } = req.params;
  if (req.params.gender === "FEMALE" || req.params.gender === "MALE") {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(URL);
      const jsonData = await response.json();
      const outputData = jsonData.map((productItem) => {
        console.log(productItem); // doesn't get printed
        // some operation
        return productItem;
      });
      await res.json(jsonData);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send("Error getting data");
    }
  } else {
    res.status(500).send("Invalid category");
  }
};
```

I'm confused about what I am missing here and making an error.

Comment: add console logging at the beginning of each of the blocks to see where the execution stops

Comment: the await response.json(); function, actually return something?

Comment: @yanirmidler Yes, it parses the data into json format. Parsed data is in jsonData variable

Comment: @Deryck console.log(123) prints 123 wherever placed inside the function.  Only the log() inside map doesnt get printed

Comment: Are you even sure `jsonData` is returning array? You can only `map` over array (iterable) objects

Comment: @ShivamSood yes, it is returning an array

Comment: What is the output of `console.log( Array.isArray( jsonData ) )`?

Comment: what i meant was, add logging around each of these key places you expect data to be returned and diplayed and see what the output is.  easier to just use a debugger for this with breakpoints and trace it down to where it's losing your info

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the code to make it clearer to understand. In general, it is best to take the fail first approach. Notice, how the first thing I do is return upon failure.

As to why you code is not printing anything out, try printing jsonData. It might be that this is an empty array.

```
const getRandomOutfit = async (req, res) => {
  const { gender, countryCode } = req.params;
  if (gender !== "FEMALE" && gender !== "MALE")
    return res.status(500).send("Invalid category");
  
  try {
    const response = await fetch(URL);
    const jsonData = await response.json();
    console.log(jsonData); // what does this return?
    const outputData = jsonData.map((productItem) => {
      console.log(productItem); // doesn't get printed
      // some operation
      return productItem;
    });
    await res.json(jsonData);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send("Error getting data");
  };
```

Comment: Thank you so much for reminding me of the fail-first approach. jsonData the parsed data - array of objects. It has value and console.log() that you had mentioned logs the data perfectly fine